# Run common jBehave story

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jbehave

I have a jBehave story as below;

```
Scenario: Setup test

GivenStories: common/story_1.story,
              common/story_2.story#{0},  
              common/story_2.story#{1},  
              common/story_3.story

Then my setup is done

Examples:
| Field1 | Field2 |
| Value1 | Value2 |
| Value3 | Value4 |
```

Now as you can see, I am using some common stories.

For each set, I want to run in the following sequence;

> Story 1 > Story 2 (with example 1) > Story 3

and then

> Story 1 > Story 2 (with example 2) > Story 3

But currently it is running in the following order;

> Story 1 > Story 2 (with example 1) > Story 2 (with example 2) >  Story
>   3

So as you can see, the issue is that story 2 is getting called back to back (with each example).

How do I make them run separately with each example?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be solved by using @BeforeStory and @AfterStory for yours story1 and story 3.

take a look at http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/annotations.html